# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore

Tags: wso2-esb

Hi Got the below excption while running the Wso2 Esb Client java code with security  with Jdk 1.5 version and Could you please provide the solution..

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore  at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)     at
> org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:155)     at
> org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.getTokenStorage(RampartMessageData.java:639)
> at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:138)
> at
> org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:318)     at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:254)    at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:160)   at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
> at
> WSO2.WSO2_Axis2_Client19.UpdateAssetStatusSecuirtyStub.updateAssetStatusSecurity(UpdateAssetStatusSecuirtyStub.java:193)
> at
> WSO2.WSO2_Axis2_Client19.UpdateAssetClientProgram.main(UpdateAssetClientProgram.java:94)
> 29 Jul, 2015 2:30:33 PM org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader loadClass
> WARNING: org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore  at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)     at
> org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:185)     at
> org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:163)     at
> org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.getTokenStorage(RampartMessageData.java:639)
> at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:138)
> at
> org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:318)     at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:254)    at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:160)   at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
> at
> WSO2.WSO2_Axis2_Client19.UpdateAssetStatusSecuirtyStub.updateAssetStatusSecurity(UpdateAssetStatusSecuirtyStub.java:193)
> at
> WSO2.WSO2_Axis2_Client19.UpdateAssetClientProgram.main(UpdateAssetClientProgram.java:94)
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Undefined
> 'WSHandler: cannot load token storage class:
> org.wso2.carbon.security.util.SecurityTokenStore' resource property
> at
> org.apache.rampart.RampartException.getMessage(RampartException.java:81)
> at
> org.apache.rampart.RampartException.(RampartException.java:61)
> at
> org.apache.rampart.RampartException.(RampartException.java:67)
> at
> org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.getTokenStorage(RampartMessageData.java:641)
> at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:138)
> at
> org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:318)     at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:254)    at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:160)   at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
> at
> WSO2.WSO2_Axis2_Client19.UpdateAssetStatusSecuirtyStub.updateAssetStatusSecurity(UpdateAssetStatusSecuirtyStub.java:193)
> at
> WSO2.WSO2_Axis2_Client19.UpdateAssetClientProgram.main(UpdateAssetClientProgram.java:94)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with jdk 1.7 in java client. it worked after adding the correct `org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt` maven dependency.